# Dual Monitor with Nvidia graphics: damaged 'Displays'

Tags: nvidia, compiz, multiple-monitors

I just got ubuntu 12.04 and the graphical options were working fine with one monitor.

After installing the second monitor there are many glitches and issues. Too many, sadly. I am asking here about one in particular:

If I execute: Displays under System settings I get the error: "RANDR extension is not present".

Sometimes after moving windows or switching workspaces I get an error saying that compiz crashed too.

Any thoughts/solutions on that?

I am using:
GeForce 9400 GT, 512 MB
Nvidia dryver: 295.40

Comment: After all this time this problem is still present and I think it may be related to this other question http://askubuntu.com/questions/159545/why-does-unity-2d-breaks-ubuntu-12-04-fatal-error-missing-composite-extension

Answer (score 0):

Use Nvidia-Settings and enable twinview. Apart from seeing noise in video player windows after resume from hibernate I experience no issues on my notebook with a 9400 chip.